# How to indexing solr cloud with zookeeper to replicate data in all the nodes

Tags: solr, replication

Is there any way I can insert data to only one node or shard of Solrv5.x and get it replicated to all the other nodes linked to it via zookeeper.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

This is what Solr does by default when running in SolrCloud mode (which is when it's using Zookeeper).

As long as you index to one of the nodes, the nodes will figure out where (which server has the collection) the document should go and which other servers it should be replicated to.

You set these settings when [creating](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api1) or [changing a collection](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-modifycoll) through the `replicationFactor` setting.